# Rails association - multiple model abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following where a user can create a newsletter and can also subscribe to a newsletter. Is there a better way to distinguish between these two abilities with associations or can I put the ownership in the subscription model as suggested by: [multiple has_many associations in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157050/multiple-has-many-associations-in-rails). With this solution how can I code the newsletter model to get the newsletter owner and newsletter subscribers.

```
 Newsletter Model
  # fields: id, user_id
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions 
  belongs_to :user *i.e. created by a single user*

 Subscription Model
  # fields: user_id, newsletter_id
  belongs_to :newsletter
  belongs_to :user

 User Model
  # fields: id
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :newsletters, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :newsletters *i.e. created many newsletters*
  has_many :created_newsletters, :through => :subscriptions, *old answer*
           :source => :newsletter, 
           :conditions => ["newsletter.creator = ?", true]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Newsletter Model
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscriptions, source: :user 
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"

 Subscription Model
  # fields: user_id, newsletter_id
  belongs_to :newsletter
  belongs_to :user

 User Model
  # fields: id
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_newsletters, through: :subscriptions, source: :newsletter
  has_many :created_newsletters, class_name: "Newsletter", foreign_key: "user_id"
```

Now you can get subscribers and creator by doing

```
newsletter.subscribers
newsletter.creator
```

Comment: Is it also possible to say user.newsletters and user.newsletter?

Comment: Yeah, if that's what you want. But its a rails convention to have has_many association as plural

Comment: Thanks! Btw, in this form what is the technical name for the new "creator"/"subscribed_newsletters" models? I.e. can I use the same name in multiple models e.g. in addition "belongs_to :creator, class_name: "Feed", foreign_key: :user_id"" for feed.creator as well as newsletter.creator?